# django model add data to model only if boolean field is true

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

I am just learning Django. I've a model named **Jobs** which contains 3 fields:

- current_job[Boolean field]
- current_jobtitle
- current_jobcompany

I want to populate data from my admin site only if the boolean field is true.Any idea would be really helpful. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Override [ModelAdmin.save_model()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method:

```
class JobsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.current_job:
            obj.current_jobtitle = ''
            obj.current_jobcompany = ''
        obj.save()
```